# Transforming NA to specific arrays of a matrix in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix of the form,

```
mat <- matrix(1:25, 5,5)
```

that looks like the following:

[image]

Now, I need to transform this matrix in the form as shown below:

[image]

That is, I want to keep all elements of row 2 and 4 as well as column 2 and 4 and replace all other values with NA. This a just a simple example to explain the problem. My actual matrix size is about 2000 X 2000. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first and second matrices are a different in that the first one is filled as R would fill a matrix (i.e. column-major order) and the second is row-major.

Assuming that you meant to have identical matrices, your task can be addressed with simple matrix operations:

```
mat <- matrix(1:25, 5,5)
mat2 <- matrix(NA, 5,5)
mat2[c(2,4),] <- 1
mat2[,c(2,4)] <- 1
mat * mat2
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   NA    6   NA   16   NA
[2,]    2    7   12   17   22
[3,]   NA    8   NA   18   NA
[4,]    4    9   14   19   24
[5,]   NA   10   NA   20   NA
```

If not, just transpose your initial matrix with `t(mat)` and follow the same approach as above.

Comment: Instead of c(2,4) if I have a dataset of number say data$numbers, would it work?

Comment: You can use a named vector for your column and row indeces. For example `sel_rows <- c(2,4)` and then `mat2[sel_rows, ] <- 1`

So you would just want to express your dataset of numbers in terms of position index vectors.

Answer (score 0):

```
mat = t(mat)
replace(x = mat, which((matrix(row(mat) %in% c(2, 4), NROW(mat), NCOL(mat)) |
                              matrix(col(mat) %in% c(2, 4), NROW(mat), NCOL(mat))) == FALSE,
                              arr.ind = TRUE), NA)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]   NA    2   NA    4   NA
#[2,]    6    7    8    9   10
#[3,]   NA   12   NA   14   NA
#[4,]   16   17   18   19   20
#[5,]   NA   22   NA   24   NA
```

Comment: this works as well. thank you. however, instead of c(2,4) if I have a dataset of number say data$numbers, would it work?